# How to change element of a parent when hovering over a child using css

Tags: html, css

How to change the parent product bgcolor when hovering over the link or hovering over the details just using CSS?

HTML CODE

```
<div id="summary" align='center'>Products</div>
        <div id="detail" align='center'>
        <a href='http://www.3ds.com/products/catia/welcome/'>A</a></br>
        <a href='http://www.3ds.com/products/catia/welcome/'>B</a></br>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that through `CSS` only, as there is no [parent selector](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/).

However, using JavaScript, you could toggle the parent's class when the user hovers over the `a`nchor element. At which point, you'll be able to style the class that gets added on hover.

Comment: then what can i use to do this?

Comment: JQuery has function .parent(). You can read more about it: http://api.jquery.com/parent/
In the end the function might be something along this line:
`$('div.detail a').parent().css('background-color', 'red');`